# Express how to re-direct json data through different endpoints

Tags: javascript, express

I'm pretty new to using express and the responses here on StackOverflow have been very confusing. What I have is JSON data that I am retrieving using app.get(). What I want is to modify this data and send it to my index.html file. I know that I can simply use the fetch function to get the data in my index file from the get endpoint but I need to use both the app.post() and app.put() function.

Comment: So you fetch data with get, modify it, then send it back with post, right? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Here's a sample code that uses axios and plain vanilla javascript to get some data from backend and then in frontend, you can modify the data. You can replace axios for fetch and it'll still work.

**app.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 8000;

const app = express();

/* Simulating data, a better approach would be to use some storage like MySQL... */
let data = {
    name: "Elon Musk",
    age: "48",
    height: "1.88m"
};

app.use(express.static("public"));
/* body-parser is required so the server can parse the data sent. */
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

/* get the data... */
app.get("/api/mydata", function(req, res) {
    return res.json(data);
});

/* this is where the client will post the data */
app.post("/api/newdata", function(req, res) {
    data.name = req.body.name;
    data.age = req.body.age;
    return res.json("OK!");
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on 8000");
});
```

**public/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name..." value="">
    <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Age..." value="">

    <button type="button" id="setValues">Change values!</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            axios.get("/api/mydata").then(function(res) {
                document.getElementById("name").value = res.data.name;
                document.getElementById("age").value = res.data.age;
            })
        });

        document.getElementById("setValues").addEventListener("click", function() {
            axios.post("/api/newdata", { 
                name: document.getElementById("name").value,
                age: document.getElementById("age").value
            }).then(function(res) {
                console.log("Sent!");
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions, let me know!